# Loading external webpage into my page without redirecting to different URL

Tags: php, html, redirect, iframe, external

So what I want to do is create a subdomain on my website and have it load an external website into it without actually going to that website. For instance:

google.mydomain.com loads google.com but the URL bar reads google.mydomain.com.

**How do I go about doing this?**

I tried [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) but could not figure it out.

**Trying:**

iframe

1. I want page to take up the whole screen for each person's computer. Can I set it to 100% instead of x amount of pixels?
2. I want to remove scroll bars but it says not supported.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use either an Iframe, or file_get_contents();

Iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

file_get_contents():

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
?>
```

With file_get_contents(), you need to beware of the website you're fetching from using relative URL's, which will break the CSS, Images, Javascript, etc.

Comment: Absolutely perfect thank you! Just need to remove scrolls if possible, but it is barely noticeable.

Comment: Good! On the Iframe, you can use something like scrolling="no" or embed something in the CSS, such as iframe { overflow: hidden; }

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to be able to use php's include function, as this is not a resource residing on your server.

One option you could explore is loading everything in as the contents of an iframe: see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp for some details about the iframe html element

Answer (score 0):

- iframe is now not supported in html5
- it works on html5 also
- Easy to add or remove

Example:

```
 <body onload="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'"> </body>
```

Comment: How may I do this in a wordpress page?

Comment: I looked it up. <iframe> is still supported in HTML5.